# is there a way to convert an immutable list to a mutable one?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, immutability

So I wanted to create a method to add an element into an immutable list but I kinda need it to be a mutable list to be returned at the end. So far, I have have created a mutable copy of the immutable list:

```
Grid2D add(int elem) {
          List<Integer> newlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          for (int i = 0; i < this.list.size(); i++) {
              newlist.add(list.get(i));
          }   
          newlist.add(elem);
          return new Grid2D(newlist, this.numOfCols);
}
```

I was just wondering if there are any other ways to go about converting an ImList to a list? Preferably without the ArrayList package if that's possible!

Thank you for your time and any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: `newlist = new ArrayList<>(this.list)` does it.

Comment: Basically, no there aren't.  Apart from copying it ... which you say you have already tried.

Comment: @ernest_k aw I was hoping not to use the ArrayList package, but thanks!

Comment: "create a method to add an element into an immutable list" immutable means you can't add to (or remove from, or change elements of) that list. Whoever made the list immutable presumably did so specifically to avoid it being mutated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to convert an immutable list to a mutable one?

The short answer is that there isn't a way.

The long answer is that it depends what you mean by "convert" to mutable.

Obviously, you can create a mutable copy of an immutable list<sup>1</sup>.  But the downside is that the mutable list is a distinct list.  Changes made to the "immutable" list after you made the copy are not reflected in the new list.  And vice-versa.

If you were to "crack open" the immutable list abstraction, it *may be* possible to mutate it.  (Nasty reflection is involved, and you need to know how the specific immutable list class has been implemented.)  But this is a really bad idea.  Various parts of your application code-base will be assuming that the immutable collection is immutable.  Violating the invariant could make all sorts of things behave incorrectly.

Finally, if the "immutable list" was originally created using `Collections.unmodifiableList`, it is not strictly immutable.  You could potentially modify it by modifying the original list that was wrapped by the `unmodifiableList` call.

---

<sup>1 - You don't necessarily need to use `ArrayList` for this.  You could use any `List` implementation class, including a custom implementation that you wrote from scratch.  But you *do* need to use `new` to create a new `List` instance.</sup>